# trying to add FIFO queue system call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm currently taking an Operating System class at my school.

Right now, I've been trying to add some new system call that makes a queue in the kernel space.

I'm trying to do three things here:

1) make the queue(either by dynamically allocating or just declaring an array)

2) enqueue

3) dequeue

The problem is with 1).

Here's a sample code for the system call source file:

```
asmlinkage long sys_allocqueue(unsigned int size){
   int *queue = kmalloc(sizeof(int) * size, GFP_KERNEL);
   return 0;
}
```

and this is just declaring array:

```
asmlinkage long sys_allocqueue(unsigned int size){
   int queue[size];
   return 0;
}
```

Either way, I'm getting a return of -1 which is an error for syscall in a test application.

I have no clue why this is not working.

P.S.

I also found out about using kfifo.h for creating a queue, but that did not work out well either.

Comment: Definition `asmlinkage long sys_*` doesn't *automatically* add system call into the kernel, you need to modify `entry.S` file in arch-specific code for make kernel aware of new syscall entry. Just google for "adding system call into linux kernel".

Answer (score 0):

It was kernel compile problem

After compilation, while rebooting, my Ubuntu stopped, so I force quit everything and turned it back on.

The problem started afterwards.

I recompiled it and rebooted it not by sudo reboot, but just by shutting it down and turning it back on.

Now it's working again.